# KDB/q: If/else statement to append to a table

Tags: if-statement, kdb

I have a table that looks like this:

| Name | Start Time | End Time | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May | 2:45 | 3:45 | X2 |
| Bob | 2:00 | 4:00 | E9 |
| Sue | 3:45 | 5:50 | U5 |

The basic overview is that I have this initial table of people with start and end times, and there's a different database with more information on these people and their stats.

I have another function that takes in the initial table above and outputs the number of items retrieved within that time. However, if the time range for the person doesn't have any count, it will drop that row:

| Name | Start Time | End Time | ID | Items Retrieved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May | 2:45 | 3:45 | X2 | 27 |
| Bob | 2:00 | 4:00 | E9 | 32 |

I do this by using a function that looks like this:

```
fGetItemsRetrieved:{[inputTable]
    outputTable: select  Name, Start_Time, End_Time, ID, Items_Retrieved from fGetAggTable[inputTable]}
```

I have a function called isTimeRangeInData[Name; StartTime; EndTime] that returns a boolean (1b or 0b) if the time range is out of bounds for that person, so for May, because she has data in the database during that time range, it will return 1b. However, for Sue, it will return 0b.

My question is, how can I write a one- or two-liner that can look at the initial table, and call the fGetItemsRetrieved[] function, but for any line items where isTimeRangeInData[] outputs false, it still outputs a line item with some N/A value in the "Items Retrieved" column, like below?

| Name | Start Time | End Time | ID | Items Retrieved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May | 2:45 | 3:45 | X2 | 27 |
| Bob | 2:00 | 4:00 | E9 | 32 |
| Sue | 3:45 | 5:50 | U5 | N/A |

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If having a null instead of `N/A` is acceptable and assuming that `Name` can be used as a unique key, you could use a left join (`lj`).

```
q)show t:([]Name:`May`Bob;ID:`X2`E9;Items:27 32)
Name ID Items
-------------
May  X2 27
Bob  E9 32
q)([]Name:`May`Bob`Sue;ID:`X2`E9`U5)lj`Name xkey t
Name ID Items
-------------
May  X2 27
Bob  E9 32
Sue  U5
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. My one question is, can I collect all of the line items that don't pass the isTimeRangeInData[] function in a separate table? That way it can be more explicit as to which tables I need to left join

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. To collect all the rows that don’t pass isTimeRangeInData, wouldn’t you just have to invert the where clause that collects all the rows that do pass?